# Suggestions for speeding up pandas calculation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am performing the following calculation which is verrryyy slow (mostly because the DataFrame that I am looping through (`PM_mix`) is very large). I know you're not supposed to loop through DataFrames if at all possible, but I don't know the best way to avoid this. I feel like the solution may be to execute the calculation using numpy and then convert the output array to a DataFrame, but I don't know the best way to go about this. Since I am essentially trying to multiply each DataFrame column by an array (`F_range`), would it be worth trying to calculate a multidimensional array, and then flatten? I would appreciate any of your suggestions - thanks!

```
# initial modal abundances
ol_abund = 0.66
opx_abund = 0.17
cpx_abund = 0.12
gar_abund = 0.06

# melting modes
ol_meltmode = 0.0833
opx_meltmode = -0.190
cpx_meltmode = 0.8095
gar_meltmode = 0.298

# calculate bulk D
bulk_D = ol_abund*OIB_D['olivine'] + opx_abund*OIB_D['opx'] + cpx_abund*OIB_D['cpx'] + gar_abund*OIB_D['garnet']
# caclulate bulk P
bulk_P = ol_meltmode*OIB_D['olivine'] + opx_meltmode*OIB_D['opx'] + cpx_meltmode*OIB_D['cpx'] + gar_meltmode*OIB_D['garnet']

# F-range 1 - 5% (0.1% increments)
F_range = np.linspace(0.005,0.04,36)

# loop through and calculate new mixtures
df = pd.DataFrame()
melt_list = []

for col in PM_mix:
    # reset dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for F in F_range:
        # calculate melt concentration using D and P values for each F
        melt = PM_mix[col][:13]/(bulk_D + F*(1 - bulk_P))
        # append modeling parameters for each source composition
        melt = melt.append(PM_mix[col][13:20])
        df[F] = melt
    # append percent melt for each iteration
    df = df.append(pd.Series(F_range,index=df.columns,name='F'))
    melt_list.append(df)

# concatenate list of dataframes into single dataframe
all_melts = pd.concat(melt_list,axis=1)

# renumber columns of dataframe
all_melts.columns = range(np.shape(all_melts)[1])
```

`bulk_D` and `bulk_P` can be considered the same 1D array for the purposes of reproducing the problem:

```
bulk_D = array([1.78800e-04, 4.91500e-04, 2.28550e-03, 1.13606e-03, 5.21800e-03,
       1.17696e-02, 1.37100e-02, 1.85100e-02, 2.95700e-02, 4.00100e-02,
       4.25960e-02, 7.73200e-02, 3.44720e-01])
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the undefined variables (eg. `OIB_D`) so we can fully *reproduce* the problem on our machine and help you?

Comment: Sorry about that! Both bulk_D and bulk_P are 1d arrays. I have added an example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `PM_mix[col][:13]/(bulk_D + F*(1 - bulk_P))` produces a `pd.Series` with shape `(13,)`, whether `bulk_D` and `bulk_P` are arrays or constants. In my implementation, I leave them as constants.

I ran your code on a sample dataframe of size `(20,1000)` and got the run time was `24 s ± 437 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`. My faster implementation is below:

```py
PM_mix = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(20, 1000))

bulk_D = np.random.rand()
bulk_P = np.random.rand()

F_range = np.linspace(0.005,0.04,36)

# precalculate division term
weight = 1/(bulk_D + F_range*(1 - bulk_P))

# mask to exclude indices 13:20
mask_mul = np.array([1. if i < 13 else 0. for i in range(20)])

# mask to only include indices 13:20 i.e. modeling parameters
mask_add = np.array([0. if i < 13 else 1. for i in range(20)])

# values in a column of the data frame -> array of shape (21, 36)...
# (values and melt parameters x F) with additional row for F values
def col2arr(col_vals):
    return np.concatenate(
        [np.dot((col_vals*mask_mul).reshape(-1,1), weight.reshape(1,-1))
            + (col_vals*mask_add).reshape(-1,1),
        F_range.reshape(1,-1)], axis=0)

# concatenate the results of this operation for each column in PM_mix
data = np.concatenate(np.array(list(map(col2arr, PM_mix.values.T))), axis=-1)

# create new df
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# set index as your desired index
df_new.index = list(df_new.index[:-1])+['F']
```

The runtime of this is `29 ms ± 454 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)` (827 times faster).

I calculated the dataframes from both methods, and verified that they are equal as follows:

```py
>> np.allclose(df_new.values, all_melts.values)
True
```

Generally, creating extra pandas dataframes and concatenating them will slow down your code. Stick to more lightweight data structures if you can.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this out - this is super helpful. I've been coding in python for a while now but have never had any formal training, so my code can be less than efficient sometimes. It's really nice to see a more concise and efficient formatting of one of my calculations.

Comment: @ZackEriksen Happy to help! I'm self taught for the most part as well - I spent a lot of time at work writing code with pandas and I ran into similar problems to yours. After tens of headaches, I started to think of these more like linear algebra problems with matrices, and tossed out pandas until it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This could be faster.

```
def mult(F):
    y=(PM_mix.iloc[:13]/(bulk_D + F*(1 - bulk_P))).to_numpy()
    return (y[:,:,np.newaxis])

x=map(mult, F_range)
x=list(x)

w=np.concatenate(x, axis=2)

ncol=len(F_range)*PM_mix.shape[1]
w=w.reshape((13,ncol))

v=PM_mix.iloc[13:20].to_numpy()

def repe(_):
    return(v[:,:,np.newaxis])

u=map(repe, range(len(F_range)))
u=list(u)

u=np.concatenate(u, axis=2)

u=u.reshape((7,ncol))

F_range.shape=(1,len(F_range))
f=np.hstack([F_range]*PM_mix.shape[1])

t=np.concatenate([w, u, f], axis=0)

s=pd.DataFrame(t)

print(s)
```